# TFS command line and SSL/TLS security exception

Tags: command-line, tfs, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use tf.exe command line to setup a new workspace. I don't like the idea installing Team Explorer and therefore required Visual Studio.

Running tested command from the other machine where VS is installed causes security exception on this one since I am trying to connect to the TFS via https. I get the error string:

> Team Foundation Server https://... does not exist or is not accessible at this time. Technical information (for administrator):
>     The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I tried to

- ping the server => was fine
- access it via IE => had to accept the certification, but otherwise fine

Are there any other things I can try?

Many thanks,
Ovanes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our ssl certificate was signed with some proprietary certificate (issued not by a known authority like Verisign), therefore I had to install the issuer certificate as the trusted root certificate. Afterwards everything worked fine.

Many thanks for your devotion.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990.aspx)

It provides web based access to much of the functionality of Team Explorer.

> You can use Team System Web Access
>   through a remote connection to perform
>   the following functions:
>
> - Create, view, query for, and track    work items.
> - Manage a project's document libraries.
> - View version-controlled files and related version information.
> - Manage the software build process by running builds and    reviewing build
>     results.
> - Generate reports to track status and trend information over    time for a
>     team project

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur using tfpt.exe (and probably tf.exe) too, if you're using an old version.  We encountered it using TFPT 2010 against a TFS 2012 server.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue even after installing their certificates. There might be cases when the handshake between server and client don't use the same SSL or TLS version. I used the following changes ot the registry to force TLS on the client and it worked fine after that:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

More info Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityAdvisories/2015/2960358 and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/10/09/troubleshooting-tls-ssl-scenario-2/

Answer (score -1):

Have you specified TFS port? SSL drops you automatically to 443 and TFS is using, as far as I remember port 8080.

You have to specify full url including port number when you connect for the first time. For example "http://team1server:8080".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I did. The server runs on 444 port.

Comment: Can you enable HTPP (not HTTPS) connection for a moment to ensure there aren't any network problems? Let's eliminate that one first. Also, try to telnet TFS on the port you set up. It should connect.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. I am within a large enterprise. For now I can login to a domain without any problems. Since I do my tests from within a virtual machine I can save the state, install visual studio and try using the command line tools than, if it works => there is really smth. I have overseen. For now I can go to that URL in IE and it asks me to accept the certificate, what I do than.
The only point I assume can make problems is that I copied the command line tools and dependent assemblies from the other machine with the same .NET Fw version. That's it!